# How can I answer this question? (Modular)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$-3 \equiv 17$

Find the mod number.

**Ex:** $-3 \equiv 17 ~~{\rm(mod~5)}$

How would I find the mod number?

Comment: Do you mean, "*How would I find the numbers $m$ such that $-3\equiv 17\bmod m$*"?

Answer (score 4):

I take it you are told that 
$$-3\equiv 17\pmod{m}$$
and you want $m$.

The above congruence says that $m$ divides $17-(-3)$. So the possible $m$ are all the divisors of $20$. As you mentioned, $5$ is one of them.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by divisors?

Comment: $a$ is a divisor (factor) of $b$ if there is an integer $q$ such that $aq=b$. It is a matter of taste whether we restrict to positive integers or not. So the positive divisors of $20$ are $1,2,4,5,10,20$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $$-3\equiv17\pmod a\iff a\text{  divides }17-(-3)=20$$